# Google Bigquery Proximity search using Regexp

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I have title text e.g. "Top 5 most dangerous jobs in the UK".
I want to find all rows that contains word "dangerous" and the word "UK" having distance between them as 3 word.

Like in the above text it should match my condition as the text contains word "dangerous" and "UK" and the distance between them is 3 word as well.

I tried below syntax:

```
   SELECT PubName,Title
   From emp.final_month
   WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(Title,r'\b?(dangerous).*(UK)\b?')
```

(Above query gives me everything that has word "dangerous" and "UK" but not based on position between them.)

Not sure how to put position in the above query. Can anyone help in getting the right syntax for the regexp supported in BigQuery.

Syntax in Regex is also welcome.

Comment: Try `r'\bdangerous(?:\W+\w+){0,3}\W+UK\b'`

Comment: @wiktor, nope it didnt work. even if i give (0,6) it is still getting me the record where as it shouldn't since it should match only for 3 words between them.

Comment: for case insensitive, I need to do the following:   SELECT PublisherName,Headline
 From content.feed_2017_09_30
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(LOWER(Headline),r'\bdangerous\b (?:\w+[- ]){3}\buk\b'). It may help others

Comment: I understood "within" to be 0 to 3 words. Sure, you need to remove `0,` if you need *exactly* 3 words: `r'\bdangerous(?:\W+\w+){3}\W+UK\b'` and to make it case insensitive, try `r'(?i)\bdangerous(?:\W+\w+){3}\W+UK\b'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this regex:

```
\bdangerous\b (?:\w+[- ]){3}\bUK\b
```

Note that it's case sensitive, and doesn't account for punctuation between 'dangerous' and 'UK'.

```
\bdangerous\b : the word 'dangerous' followed by a space
(?:       ): a non-capturing group...
(  \w+    ): consisting of one or more word characters...
(     [- ]): followed by either a hyphen or a space...
{3}: repeated three times (i.e. three words)
\bUK\b: the word 'UK'
```

Comment: @Anthony..Thanks it works like charm. you saved my day mate. What if i have to make that as case insensitive.

Comment: Could you please explain the Regex syntax details as well. I believe it may help others especially to novice like me.

Comment: BTW, the pattern can be reduced to  `\bdangerous (?:\w+[- ]){3}UK\b`

Comment: You can try using the i flag for case insensitivity

Answer (score 3):

Try below approach as an idea for direction - it is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `emp.final_month` AS (
  SELECT 'Top 5 most dangerous jobs in the UK' AS title UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Top most dangerous 5 jobs in the UK' AS title  
),
words AS (
  SELECT title, word, pos
  FROM `emp.final_month`, UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(title, r'[\w_]+') ) AS word WITH OFFSET pos
  WHERE word IN ('dangerous', 'UK')
  ORDER BY title, pos
)
SELECT w1.title title 
FROM words w1 JOIN words w2
ON w1.title = w2.title
AND w1.word != w2.word
AND w1.pos > w2.pos
GROUP BY title
HAVING MIN(w1.pos - w2.pos - 1) = 3
```

Comment: I tried your query it work but i had to add "MAX(w1.pos - w2.pos - 1) = 3" as well. But my query query generation will be dynamic, not sure how the hard coding the text will work. I don't think in my case its a right solution. But thanks for the effort.

Comment: what you mean by "hard coding the text"?

Comment: I got it wrong. My bad..I realized few minutes ago I don't have to hard code the text. But since my query generation is dynamic I was more looking for Regex solution.

Comment: sure. hope solution in my answer will help you if you will end up with more sophisticated criteria. meantime, consider voting up if you think it is helpful